# Oscola LaTeX problem creating footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I am having some problems getting footnotes to render properly with Oscola LaTeX.

A minimal LaTeX file to illustrate my problem would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\title{Back to the Future? Learning Lessons on the Pro-Competitive Regulation of Health Services}
\author{Lindsay Stirton}

\usepackage[style=oscola, ibidtracker=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{/Users/ljs/Documents/bibs/myrefs.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Miller concludes that ``competition law could be extremely useful in deterring anticompetitive activity detrimental to the health sector.''\footcite[p. 481]{Miller:1992ve}

\end{document}
```

The BibLaTeX entry is:

```
@article{Miller:1992ve,
author = {Miller, Frances},
title = {{Competition law and anticompetitive professional behaviour affecting health care}},
journal = {The Modern Law Review},
year = {1992},
volume = {55},
number = {4},
pages = {453--481}
}
```

This would produce a footnote at the end of the sentence that typsets as:

> Frances Miller, ‘Competition law and anticompetitive professional behaviour affecting health care’ (1992) 55(4) The Modern Law Review 453 , p. 481.

Note the spacing in "453 , p. 481." Clearly I need to drop the spacing before the comma. Is there any way to do this?

Incidentally, the problem arises only with articles, not with books.

Finally, in submitting this request, I'd like to record my view that Paul Stanley has done a great service to the legal community in producing this pa

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Note that you should not force "p." and the like manually in postnotes, `oscola` by default does not print page prefixes, if you want to get, those put `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}` in your preamble, `biblatex` will then automatically chose "p" or "pp". If you do not like that `oscola` drops the dots after "p" and "pp" add them by modifying the `.lbx` file (`oscola` seems to drop all dots in abbreviation in its `.lbx` file).

Comment: I'm sorry I missed this. There was a bug in the package. The current version on CTAN should correct it. BTW, please don't hesitate to email me with things like this -- I'm much more likely to notice email than something here, especially when I'm busy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about problem that was solved by a bugfix in the package (see comment above).